# Invalid hash error in stripe passing metadata to customer stripe

Tags: php, hash, metadata

I am passing metadata while creating customer and response is as shown in attachment using stripe api in php. but it is throwing Invalid hash error. can someone please help.

I am stuck for 2 days now.[image]

Comment: Would be useful if you could provide the entire metadata you're trying to attach.

Answer (score 0):

Metadata has some rules: "You can specify up to 50 keys, with key names up to 40 characters long and values up to 500 characters long."
https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata